# How to support same margin in all browser

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a dive with an image. I give margin in div class full_logo_login. It works in firefox, but not work in chrome; my CSSis given below:

```
.full_logo_login{
    height: 345px;
     margin: 7% 0 7% 23%;
 }
.full_logo_login > img {
 height: 345px;
 width: 345px;
 }
```

*margin: 7% 0 7% 23%;* is perfectly working in firefox but in chrome, it's not working. chrome want *margin: 2% 0 7% 23%;* to work perfectly. So I've written this CSS:

```
.full_logo_login{
    height: 345px;
     -webkit-margin:2% 0 7% 23% !important;
     margin: 7% 0 7% 23%;
 }
.full_logo_login > img {
 height: 345px;
 width: 345px;
 }
```

But still now my chrome browser not working, chrome still now accepting *margin: 7% 0 7% 23%;* 
my full code is:

```
<style type="text/css">
.full_login_box {
  background: #202144 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 7% auto;
  width: 100% !important;
}
.full_logo_login{
    height: 345px;
     -webkit-margin:2% 0 7% 23% !important;
     margin: 7% 0 7% 23%;
 }
.full_logo_login > img {
 height: 345px;
 width: 345px;
 }
</style>

html:


<div class="full_login_box">
    <div class="full_logo_login">
        <img src="img/loginlogo.png">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Make the browsers render all elements more consistently  - https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer
Need to use this css `-webkit-margin-before:2%`